# Why doesn't a regex containing $ (built from a string) work?

Tags: javascript, regex

This works:

```
var r="xS";
var regex = new RegExp(r); // Anchor at the end
var s="axS";
s = s.replace( regex, "Z" );
// Now, s is "aZ"
```

But this doesn't

```
var r="x$";
var regex = new RegExp(r); // Anchor at the end
var s="ax$";
s = s.replace( regex, "Z" );
// Now, s is STILL "ax$". NOT "aZ".
```

This doesn't work no matter where "$" is in the string `r` - e.g even if it's not at the end.

Comment: In the second bit of code, r is "x$$". Why would the the two $ symbols behave differently from each other?

Comment: @MichaelMyers - I removed the $ from the end of the regex. It was a red herring from exiting code (right-side anchor) but didn't affect the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to look for a `$` in a string, you need to escape it.  The `$` is a special character in regexes meaning "end of string".

```
var r="x\$";
var regex = new RegExp( r + "$" ); // Anchor at the end
```

Comment: Gotcha. For some reason I thought (errorneously) that RegExp would escape it automagically.

Comment: @DVK: It can't, how would it know what you're trying to do?  And if it did, how would you use special characters? :-P

Comment: I said "for **some** reason", not for "for sane reason" :)

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, "ax$" is a literal string which contains the character '$'.  The regex (`r`) does not contain the literal character, but instead contains two anchors.  You need to escape the '$' in the regex to match a literal value.

`var r = "x\$";` should do the trick.